# App that scans, saves, and then displays QR codes back _exactly_ as they were scanned

Tags: android, qr-code

Now and then I get QR codes for events, and they're mostly sent on PDF files.

I obviously don't want to print the PDF, but opening it on my phone and awkwardly zooming in on the code is, well, awkward.

There are QR code scanners and wallets that can scan and read QR codes, and save them and the content in some sort of digital wallet.

However, when I then open the saved code in the app, the QR code shown is always different from the one I scanned.

I tried several apps (ONE Wallet, Passes, PassAndroid), and they all have the same problem. The code saved & shown is not the same as the code I originally scanned.

Is there an app out there that can scan, save, and then show a QR code on my screen that looks *exactly* the same as the one scanned?

(Explanations on why this happens or how to fix this in the mentioned apps are also welcome. I thought it could have something to do with the error correction level in the codes, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.)

Comment: When generating the QR code you can chose how much redundancy (also called ecc) you want to include. Additionally some QR code are ingeniously "manipulated": e.g. if the QR code contains a small logo or a similar graphical element. These logos are not part or the QR code, instead they have been applied after QR code generation. A QR code parameter description can be e.g. found here: https://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/

Comment: Is screenshotting the PDF and cropping the image not a solution? Or are there particular reasons why it must be the same QR (e.g. visual inspection by the scanner operator)?